# OSX terminal command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I'm following a guide to setup airport in monitoring mode to do my networking exercise. I've made a shortcut to airport using this command:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

If I navigate to `/usr/sbin/airport` and display the contents with `ls` I can clearly see airport in there.

If I try to type `airport -l` or even just airport I get:

```
-bash: airport: command not found
```

Why doesn't he recognise my command?

NB: I am in the correct directory when I type that command

Comment: A couple of questions: * Have you restarted the Terminal app, or at least closed the session (window) in which you created your link and opened a new one? Path functions are sometimes odd in-between sessions.
* On that same line of thought, what happens if you type the full path to the alias? That is, instead of just `airport`, type `/usr/sbin/airport` For what it's worth, I pasted your `ln -s` command and I am able to use `airport` with no problem. I was NOT able to before, so the symlink works as presented. *Note: I don't yet have enough reputation to post this as a comment, or I would have.